# How to transfer DI requestscope to an other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-injection, ninject

Context:

I am using DI in my Web application. (I am using NInject, but hopefully this should not matter)

Some places constructor injection is not possible, for example in my custom `log4net` database logger (that's not me, who instantiates my custom logger instead the `log4net` framework). So I am using my DI container there in service locator DP mode, and asking an instance resolve explicitly in the logger code.

Note this is just a sample, in many other cases I had to use `NInject` as service locator DP instead of constructor injection.

Now the problem: 
I have an IAuditContextProvider which serves current request's audit data, like IP etc. The question arises how I configure my DI container to instantiate a concrete provider. So far I've used a request scope (singleton by request) what is supported out of box by NInject.

However recently I faced the fact I had to start a background processing initiated by a request.  This is done by

```
// This is 'outside' it's actually a request serving method running in the request context, btw it is an MVC action method,
// Pseudo code:
var auditProvider = Locator.Resolve<IAuditProvider>()

Task.Run(() =>
{
     // I would like to get the very same resolved auditProvider instance here as outside.
     // Please note: outer local variables are not solution, because of implicit calls here inside, for example if there is a logging statement here, then the service locator in the custom logger must resolve the very same instance as outside

    // Some how I must 'stamp' this thread to be the 'same' as the outside 
    // request thread in point of view of my custom scope resolver (see below) 
}
```

Note: Configuring the DI container a wide scoped singleton are not solution because of multiple requests are server parallel, and they can not use a common auditProvider.

OK, I thought this is what for custom (resolving) scopes are for. Here is the pseudo code how I am configuring my DI container:

```
kernel
  .Bind(typeof(IAuditContextProvider))
  .To(typeof(WebAuditContextProvider)).InScope(dummy =>
  {
       // Here I have to return a very same object/number/id when in
       // 'outside' the request thread, and inside the worker thread. 
       // This   way I hopefully get the very same instance when resolving.

       // To be short: I have no idea how?

  });
```

Comment: Can't you just resolve the type outside of the `Task.Run` and then pass it directly? Do you really need to run this as a background task? It's generally a bad idea to start background tasks in ASP.NET. If all else fails, have a look at `AsyncLocal`, but that should really be a last resort - if you're trying to implement dependency injection, it's kind of weird to depend on global state variables somewhere. It's dangerous, and kind of against the whole idea of dependency injection in the first place :D

Comment: 1) The user initiate a long (database) processing by pressing a button on the Web UI. How can I accomplish this without an async task?. 2) I am not using 'globals' I am using context bound instances. This is not against DI, indeed, this is one of the reason why DI is to not pass directly instances either implicitly or explicitly. With your terms a request scoped singleton would be a "global", but the fact that considered well accepted DI practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good answer for your question within the current bounds.

I do have an alternative suggestion - just perform the work synchronously in another process. This would require a form of inter-process communication (IPC) but shouldn't be too difficult.

A simple but effective form of IPC is just writing a record to a database table (acting like a queue) and having a windows service/daemon polling for new records to "process".  In this example, you would put a record in the table with the contextual information (user id, etc) and the service would utilize this context to perform the work synchronously, but the workflow would be  asynchronous to the Web UI.

This also has a nice side benefit:  You can start to build monitoring, retry logic, etc into the service.  These things are much harder to do reliably within an ASP.NET model.

You could forgo the database queue completely by using something like message queues/buses/events, but the basic concept is the same.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Unfortunatelly the solution must run as an Azure web site so starting other processes (btw I expect 1000s of users) not an option. About monitoring: The whole progress of the operation is persisted in DB and cancel flag also implemented there, so monitoring the progress, and cancelling is fully implemented.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660224/ninject-scope-issue-with-tasks-threads

Comment: Thx for the link. Actually it is close shot, but I still can not apply in my case. Please note that I must instantiate an IAuditContextProvider implementation in pure requests too (one by request) where there is no background task started. The issue is "How to get this very same instance what already instantiated in the request in a background thread using DI".

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Update:</strike>

Did you try to use closures in C#? Like this:

```
var auditProvider = Locator.Resolve<IAuditProvider>()

Task.Run(() =>
{
    // with closure you'll get that very variable you need:
    auditProvider.SomeMethod();
}
```

You should read [whole article about closures by John Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx) and how they can help you together with TPL.

**Other useful information:**
Such DI is being called as `Ambient Context` in famous book [`Dependency Injection` by M. Seeman](http://www.manning.com/seemann/):

> A truly universal CROSS-CUTTING CONCERN can potentially pollute a large part of the API for an application if you have to pass an instance around to every collaborator. An alternative is to define a context that’s available to anyone who needs it and that can be ignored by everyone else.
>
> The AMBIENT CONTEXT is available to any consumer via a static property
>   or method. A consuming class might use it like this:
>
> ```
> public string GetMessage() { return SomeContext.Current.SomeValue; }
> ```
>
> In this case, the context has a static `Current` property that a consumer can access. This property may be truly static, or may be associated with the currently executing thread. To be useful in DI scenarios, the context itself must be an ABSTRACTION and it must be possible to modify the context from the outside—in the previous example, this means that the `Current` property must be writable. The context itself might be implemented as shown in the following listing.
>
> The context is an `abstract` class, which allows us to replace one context with another implementation at runtime.

```
public abstract class SomeContext
{
    public static SomeContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            // Get current context from TLS
            var ctx = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("SomeContext")) as SomeContext;
            if (ctx == null)
            {
                ctx = SomeContext.Default;
                Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("SomeContext"), ctx);
            }
            return ctx;
        }

        set
        {
            Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("SomeContext"), value);
        }
    }

    public static SomeContext Default = new DefaultContext();
    public abstract string SomeValue { get; }
}
```

`TLS` here stands for [`Thread Local Storage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749.aspx), which can be useful idea for you here.

Also I suggest you to read about `OperationContext` class, which can be helpful for you if you want to pass some context for your `Task`, something like this:

```
// save current context before task start
var operationContext = OperationContext.Current;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // set current operation context inside your Task with closure
    OperationContext.Current = operationContext;
    // Your work here
}
```

Comment: I've mentioned in my original question that using closures are not solution for this case because some places I must use my DI container as locator and get the instance (like in log4net database logger, where it is not my code which is instantiates the logger)

Comment: Then you have to implement you own context, as I suggested in the rest of my answer.